# How to install ImageMagick on Windows 7 (2)

Tags: imagemagick, imagick, php

Hopefully, despite similar question titles, this isn't a duplicate issue.

I've installed `ImageMagick-6.7.5-6-Q16-windows-dll.exe`.

I have `php_imagick_dyn-Q16.dll` renamed to `php_imagick.dll` in PHP's `ext` directory.

I have `extension=php_imagick.dll` in my `php.ini`.

I try to run a basic test: `php -r "var_dump(class_exists('Imagick'));"`.

I get this error:

> PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialise module
>   Module compiled with module API=20060613
>   PHP compiled with module API=20090626
>   These options must match.

---

> CLI has stopped working.
>   Windows can check online for a solution to the problem.
>   > Check online for a solution and close the program
>   > Close the program

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using one of the more [up to date versions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows)?

Comment: Yes, in fact I have the most up-to-date version of the `.exe`.

Comment: The download page lists 6.7.5-6 as the most recent version. Looks like the one you have here is a couple versions behind.

Comment: I'm on Windows. Latest Windows version if 6.5.8-7.

Comment: I might just be missing something very obvious, but it really looks like 6.7.5-6 is the latest Windows release. The page lists ImageMagick-6.7.5-6-Q16-windows-dll.exe as the recommended download. The 6.5.8-7 release looks like it was from 2009.

Comment: Call me stupid, but I just looked at the version string again and I swear it changed :p nah, it's my bad. But yeah, I have the latest version.

Comment: I'm just glad I wasn't being crazy!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. First install :
   [Link](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)
2. Download :
   http://www.sk89q.com/2010/03/vc6-windows-binaries-for-imagick-2-3-0/
3. Choose the *TS* one
4. Open your *php.ini* file
5. Add this line :

   *extension=php_imagick.dll*
6. Restart your apache server

   *open php_info()*

Now your imagick lib is ready to use.

This works for me.

Comment: I followed this answer exactly: a) install latest ImageMagick for Windows, b) Download the TS windows binary, and add the extension to the php/ext directory as well as write extension=php_imagick.dll, and restarted my apache.  Didn't work.  I'm using PHP 5.3.27.  Ideas welcome.