# Installation links for Imagemagick when working with CarrierWave fileuploads in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to resize my files while uploading it using **CarrierWave** approach in ruby on rails. I have installed all the necessary gem and verything is working fine except that when I want to resize image. it throws error

**Image Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: You must have ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick**

From the error messages above I guess that I need to install **Imagemagick** so I reference solution found here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9365758/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7-2) in order to obtain the download link but the link in the solutions is no longer valid and imagemagick download seems to be for php.

What I want: Can someone point to me a secured download links for **imagemagick** that is compatible with CarrierWave fileuploads for ruby on rails applications that.

Am using windows 7

Thanks

```
    class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
      include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
      include CarrierWave::MimeTypes 

      version :thumb do
  #version :medium do

      # change the word 'fit' to 'fill'
      process resize_to_fill: [20,20]
  end
```

## coding continues..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download ImageMagick windows binaries here https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows